# How does CatBoost perform multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, catboost

I am trying to figure out how CatBoost performs multiclass classification with MultiClass loss function. As I understand it, for each prediction MultiClass requires M values for each of M classes. My questions are:

- How are those M values are obtained?
- How  are those M values are transferred to predicted probabilities?

My current hypothesis is that CatBoost builds separate binary classifier for each of M classes and then uses softmax function to get the predicted probabilities.

- If this is the case, is every sequence of trees for individual classifiers the same or completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some other common GBMs, I've seen that they work as your hypothesis, building the one-vs-rest classifiers (completely different in general) and then at the end applying softmax to recover final predictions.

But apparently CatBoost builds one set of multi-output trees:
https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1806

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a look at [Catboost  json tutorial](https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/model_analysis/model_export_as_json_tutorial.ipynb), and it seems the same tree is used for all classes.